# creating functions with multiple parameters in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, function

I am practicing creating functions in swift, and I am trying to understand parameters with multiple arguments which i've created a func named "didSwipeRight" that accepts 2 arguments and returns a Boolean.  Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong when calling multiple augments inside of a function? *Ps i've tried returning false after the else statement, as well as nil, and void, which i've switched the  swipeLeft: void but I am still receiving errors when creating this function.

```
import Foundation

func didSwipeRight(swipeRight: Bool, swipeLeft: Bool  ) {

    if swipeRight {

        return "Contact Seller"

    } else { 

        return nil

    }


}
```

Comment: For one thing, you cannot say `return "Contact Seller"` or `return nil` because this function doesn't _have_ any return type. The only thing you can say is `return`, plain and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the return type to your function declaration, in your case this is an Optional String (indicated by -> String?):

```
func didSwipeRight(swipeRight: Bool, swipeLeft: Bool) -> String? {
  if swipeRight {
    return "Contact Seller"
  } else { 
    return nil
  }
}
```

You could also leave away your second parameter *swipeLeft: Bool* as you do not use it within your function.

Comment: I did this & it doesnt work